# Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я недавно начал изучать **javascript**  и столкнулся вроде бы не совсем сложной ошибкой. Причину знаю из за чего, но не могу найти в коде месте где и как указать, чтоб получить `json`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {getAllStudents} from './client';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    getAllStudents().then(res => res.json().then(students => {
      console.log(students);
    }));
    return <h1>Hello World Spring Boot</h1>;
  }
}


export default App;

import fetch from 'unfetch';

export const getAllStudents = () => fetch('/students');
```

Comment: `json` приведите.

Comment: очевидно `/students` запрос отдает Html а не json